# How do you horizontally align a div after a wrap?

Tags: css

Let's say we have 9 divs to display as float:left, each 350px wide and the heights are given as 200, 400, 300, 350, 300, 200, 450, 100 and 400. The window can fit only 4 of them in a row. What I am observing is that the 1st 4 div display as expected, but the 5th div (after the wrap) starts at x=700, under div3. We can not be sure after which div there is going to be a wrap, but whenever it happens, we want it to start at 0, i.e., div 5 should appear below div1 and so on, e.g., expecting div9 to be under div5. How can we achieve this? Thank you.

```
<html>
    <body style="padding:20px;">
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:200 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/></div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:400 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/></div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:300 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/></div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:350 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/></div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:300 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> </div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:200 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/></div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:450 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/></div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:100 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 8 <br/> div 8 <br/></div>
            <div style="float:left; width:350; height:400 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Have you looked at CSS grid or flexbox?

Comment: No, I have not. Could you give me a pointer please?

Comment: does clearfix helps?

Comment: I think it is better that you use from percentage instead of 'px' for the divs widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `display: flex;` and then `flex-wrap: wrap;` property in your body tag. 
**Also add unit like `px`, `rem` etc ;to the height and width property of the divs**

```html
<body style="padding:20px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="width:350px; height:200px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/></div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:400px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/></div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:300px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/></div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:350px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/></div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:300px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> </div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:200px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/></div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:450px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/></div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:100px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 8 <br/> div 8 <br/></div>
  <div style="width:350px; height:400px; border:3px solid #cacafe">div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `float` styles can be removed when using flex.

Comment: I know, I forgot to remove them. Thanks for informing

Comment: it will not solve the problem wisely as divs will not fit in well vertically.

Comment: It is pretty obviously that this will not solve the problem wisely. But he only asked that how could he place the 1st div should be below 5th div and so on. And this is the answer of that question only

Answer (score 1):

using flex is optimal

```
<html>
        <body style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; padding:20px;">
                <div style="width:350; height:200 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/></div>
                <div style="width:350; height:400 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/></div>
                <div style="width:350; height:300 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/></div>
                <div style="width:350; height:350 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/></div>
                <div style="width:350; height:300 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> </div>
                <div style="width:350; height:200 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/></div>
                <div style="width:350; height:450 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/></div>
                <div style="width:350; height:100 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 8 <br/> div 8 <br/></div>
                <div style="width:350; height:400 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it will not solve the problem wisely as divs will not fit in well vertically.

Answer (score 0):

use

`.className{ clear:both; }`

```
<html>
    <body style="padding:20px;">
        <div style="float:left; width:350; height:200 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/> div 1 <br/></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:350; height:400 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/> div 2 <br/></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:350; height:300 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/> div 3 <br/></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:350; height:350 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/> div 4 <br/></div>
        <div style="float:left; clear:both; width:350; height:300 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> div 5 <br/> </div>
        <div style="float:left; width:350; height:200 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/> div 6 <br/></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:350; height:450 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/> div 7 <br/></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:350; height:100 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 8 <br/> div 8 <br/></div>
        <div style="float:left; clear:both; width:350; height:400 border:3px solid #cacafe">div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/> div 9 <br/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

it will solve the problem.
Cheers!

Comment: This will not work. We do not which div causes the wrap. So we do not know which div to put the "clear:both;" on. Thanks to fubar and Gahan Vig, flex and flex-wrap solved the problem.

Comment: it’s clear which div need to set property as clear:both; just after 4th, 8th, 12th ..

Comment: No, it is not - if the window is shrunk by the user (say, reduced width), then clear:both might have to be applied after 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc. My point of the question was that this information (window width) is not known in advance and can change dynamically.

Comment: PS: If I wanted to hardcode the breaks after 4th, 8th, ... etc., I'd have used a table to solve the issue.